# Derivative of a function with respect to a function

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds, semi-riemannian-geometry

This is Definition 10 from *Semi-Riemannian Geometry With Applications to Relativity* by Barrett O'Neill, page 7:
[image]

On both sides of Definition 10, he is differentiating with respect to ***functions***, not independent variables. What does that mean?

He defines both *x<sup>i</sup>* and *u<sup>i</sup>* to be functions, not coordinates.
He does so on the first two pages of the book:
[image]

Here's a picture of what the functions do:

[image]

Comment: Essentially $\frac{\partial (f\circ \xi^{-1} )}{\partial u^i} (\xi (p)) = \partial_i( f\circ \xi^{-1})  (\xi(p))$ by definition, where $\partial_i$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to the $i-th$ variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with multivariable calculus. On the plane, you should have no qualms with the fact that the coordinates $x, y$ are functions $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$. If you were to take the function $x$ alone, it doesn't make sense to talk about a partial derivative $\partial/\partial x;$ but when you have $x$ and $y$ together, you have a complete coordinate system, and thus you can define $\partial/\partial x$ by holding $y$ constant.

The situation on manifolds is the same - once you have fixed a coordinate system, you can define corresponding partial derivatives. Definition 10 is doing exactly this - for a *coordinate system* $x^i,$ we are defining the corresponding partial derivative operators.  Note that this definition *does not* allow you to obtain e.g. $\partial/\partial x^1$ from the function $x^1$ alone - you need to know more about $\xi.$

Remember that the $\partial/\partial x^i$ on the left side of the equation is *what is being defined* - so to interpret it rigorously we just need to make sense of the right side. On the right side we have derivatives with respect to the standard coordinates $u^i$ on $\mathbb R^n$ - these are not some exotic "derivatives with respect to functions", but just the usual partial derivatives in $\mathbb R^n,$ like the $\partial/\partial x$ I discussed earlier.

Comment: Not really.  Look at the text. The u<sup>i</sup> things are defined as functions by this author, not as numbers. I think it's just the common identification of functions with their output.

Comment: @John: Coordinates are only numbers when you're talking about the coordinates of a *single point*. If you want to talk about coordinates over a set, they are functions of the point. If this use of language clashes with your conventions, that's okay; just know that it's totally normal in the field, and take $\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}$ to be just a symbol for the $i^{\rm th}$ partial derivative in $\mathbb R^n$.